# For the PiCameraCircularIO class 'copy_to()' function, what would be the type for 'first_frame' for a stream outputting in Mjpeg?

Tags: python, camera, video-streaming, video-capture

I am trying to copy the contents of a PiCameraCircularIO stream where the output is in MJPEG format. I used the copy_to() function which requires the 'first_frame' type.

I thought it would be '.jpeg' however nothing was copied over.

```
def clip_buffer():
    global ELAPSED_TIME
    global THREAD_IS_RUN
    global INTERV
    i = 0

    while THREAD_IS_RUN:
        try:
            print('Thread is run')
            print('Making name')
            clipname = 'clip' + str(i) + '.mjpeg'
            print(clipname)
            print('waiting')
            camera.wait_recording(35)
            print('camera waited')
            output.buffer.copy_to(clipname)
            i+=1
            print(clipname + ' clipped')
            ELAPSED_TIME += INTERV
        except:
            print(i)
```

'output' is the circularIO stream

I want the resulting clips to be of type mjpeg, but what I get are empty files.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Setting `first_frame` to `None` solves the problem. Solution found here:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=229112